# Looking for short story or novelette written mid century dealing with the pitfalls of time travel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

There is something classical about this story. A big game hunter signs on to a hunt that takes him through time to the Jurassic. The rules here are a little confused. So there is a bit of willing suspension of disbelief. The hunter is warned to under no circumstances leave a well demarcated trail as he hunts for a dinosaur. Lest he disturb the slightest thing in that time frame. The implication being that the ramifications of the tiniest perturbations magnified over millions of years can seriously change the future. Somehow the effect of the killing of a dinosaur in my memory is either ignored or explained away inadequately. Predictably the hunter steps or slips off trail crushing an insect. When he returns to his present every thing is just a little off and he cannot regain the perspective of being home.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like *A Sound of Thunder*, but I only saw the cheesy action movie, so I'll let someone else chime in.

Comment: Yes that sounds right and I'm OK closing the question. I'm just too new at this to know the operational protocol. Help?

Comment: One last comment would be that Ray's premise needs to be updated as the biomass of flesh and the millions of micro organisms altered in the path of the bullets far outweighs the butterfly or even the mud on his boot.

Comment: Hey all my question has only been identified in the comments section . No actual answer has been posted for me to click on . So I don't know how to formally acknowledge that it has satisfactorily been answered so it can be closed as answered. And the person who asked the other question claims his question is different. I don't want to step on his toes. But I don't want to step on mine if I don't need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From all the information that has come in I have to conclude and agree that the story is Ray Bradbury's - The Sound of Thunder. Thanks everybody!